# How to use SDMX REST API in R to query exchange rates?

Tags: r

Hello I am trying to use this SMDX REST API in **R** to query exchange rates from the IMF data portal for either of the three URLs in the code below. However I always get a timeout error:

> "Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : Timeout was reached: [dataservices.imf.org] Connection timeout after 10003 ms"

What am I doing wrong?

```
rm(list = ls())

library(httr)
library(XML)
library(xml2)

url <- "http://dataservices.imf.org/REST/SDMX_XML.svc/CompactData/IFS/A..ENDE_XDC_USD_RATE+EDNA_USD_XDC_RATE"
url <- "http://dataservices.imf.org/REST/SDMX_XML.svc/Dataflow"
url <- "http://dataservices.imf.org/REST/SDMX_XML.svc/DataStructure/IFS"

response <- GET(url)
response <- retry(GET(url), times = 3, sleep = 5)

if (http_status(response)$status_code == 200) {
  content <- content(response, "text")
  xml_data <- xmlTreeParse(content, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
} else {
  stop("Error: Unable to fetch data from the API")
}
```

Comment: are you getting it on the first `GET` or on the `retry(GET`? Are you able to get to the URL in a regular browser? There may be a header needed to convince the remote server to respond. Other thoughts: firewalls (personal, corporate, government), network glitches.